# Responsive Lightbox not centering content

Tags: css, center

I am working with this demo: http://blog.templatemonster.com/demos/coding-a-responsive-lightbox-image-gallery-for-website-portfolios/demo/index.html

From here: http://blog.templatemonster.com/2014/05/20/coding-responsive-lightbox-gallery-portfolios-tutorial/

Is there a way to center the thumbnails? It looks like the right is off by about 25px.

Comment: please show us what code you have so far.

Comment: They look ok on Chrome. On what browser & version are you testing?

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/lg1oavwf

I think it is being caused somewhere in the css settings.

Comment: I am working with Safari 5.1, maybe that's the problem?
I also tested with Chrome and it's giving me the same error.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what I see: http://oi61.tinypic.com/e3x2u.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the float, set to inline-block instead.

Give the margin 10px to the left and 10px to the right instead of a flat 20px to the right.

From:

```
#portfolio li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

To:

```
#portfolio li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```